# jQuery text change from HTML range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new at jQuery, so I expect there is an easy answer.

I have a JSON file with different text strings for different dates. I also have an html range slider that I uses the `<datalist>` tag to define specific dates on the slider. I have written a `$.getJSON` function that nests a `$.each()` function to pull the strings from the JSON file.

I need to write in the functionality to display different strings based on the slider position.

This is my jQuery:

```
var location = $('#state-dates')[0];

$(document).on('input', '#state-dates', function() {
  if (location === 1911) {
    $.getJSON('Arizona.json', function(inputOne){
      $.each(inputOne.first, function(i, field){
        $("#leg-control").html(field.legControl);
      });
    });
  }
  else if (location === 1943) {
    $.getJSON('Arizona.json', function(inputTwo){
      $.each(inputTwo.second, function(i, field){
        $("#leg-control").html(field.legControl);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="1911" max="2013" class="bar" step=".1" list="date-list" value="1911" id="state-dates">
```

Is there a different jQuery method that I should be using to detect the change in the slider, and so display the new string? I also realize that I should probably use < or > instead of = since I want the same text to only change when it reaches a new defined position. Thank you!

**EDIT**

To help clarify, I'm adding in the relevant JSON and HTML.

JSON:

```
{ 
  "first": [
    {
      "legControl": "Not recorded",
    }],
  "second": [
    {
      "leg-control": "Democratic",
    }]
}
```

And the HTML for entering the text:

```
<div class="json-text">
    <p class="fill-in" id="leg-control"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: "Change in slider" - what slider? None of your code actually appears to reference a slider.  Many well-written slider libraries support a "callback" when the slide changes, which you could leverage to update the text.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. The slider is built in HTML, it's included at the bottom of the question, under the jQuery code.

Comment: `#leg-control`? `inputOne`? `inputTwo`? HTML and JSON is needed more than likely.

Comment: I've added the JSON and HTML with #leg-control to help clarify what I'm trying to do. "inputOne" and "inputTwo" might not need to be different, I wasn't sure if that would be better practice so that's why they're different instead of both just being "input"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a solution with a web developer friend of mine, so in case anyone else stumbles across this question, the solution I used:

```
  //call the JSON file and store it as a variable called jdata
$.getJSON('Arizona.json', function(json) {
  jdata = json;
});

var slider = $('#sliderValue')[0];

slider.oninput = function() {
var position = this.value;
var jrows = $(jdata).filter(function (i, n) {
  return n.sYear <= position && n.eYear > position;
});
  $("#year-start").html(jrows[0].jsonLineOne);
  $("#year-end").html(jrows[0].jsonLineTwo);

};
```

Essentially this takes the slider input, and runs a return command to check the position. If it is within the bounds of one subsection of the JSON file, then that section is pulled. Hopefully this helps anyone else who comes across it in the future.